# DateTime as empty String or null ?How to check?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Q:

I want to check the DateTime against `null value` to empty the cell in my report if the datetime  is null.but i don't know how to do this :it appears like this `1/1/0001` if it was null.and  i want it to be empty cell.

This is the datatype in my dataset :

[image]

and this is the expression value of my column :

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2)
```

Comment: You could check with `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: DateTime *cannot* be null. Perhaps you want to check it against DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: `= IIf(FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2)= DateTime.`

no `MinValue`

Comment: then how to check against the minimum value in my report?

Comment: Is it so that null values are inserted as DateTime MinValue in your database ? i think those values should be going in as nulls which will eventually help you sort this out

Comment: @ V4Vendetta : I want to check against the minimum value ?

like this expression :

`= IIf(FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2)`

Comment: but i don't know how to write it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IIf(FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2)=CDate("1/1/0001"),"",FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2))
```

Thanks a lot ,i think this fixes my problem.

Answer (score 9):

As I told you in my comment, you should check if your date is `DateTime.MinValue` (the minimum value a date can assume, which is exactly 01/01/0001).

```
if (your_date_property == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: Could u write the expression please?

Comment: hmmm , this is a report so the expression will be like this :

`= IIf(FormatDateTime(Fields!D_DateTime.Value,2),....`

Comment: Comparing to `default(DateTime)` assumes less knowledge about the initialization of date time and is good for all struct (and class) types.

Answer (score 1):

As datetime is a struct rather than class i.e. a value type rather than a reference type; it must be initialized with some value. It cannot have null values.

Hence to check the default value you should check the equality with DateTime.MinValue

i.e.

```
if(D_DateTime.Value == DateTime.MinValue)
{
   //write code here for default value handling
}
```

Comment: Comparing to default(DateTime) assumes less knowledge about the initialization of date time and is good for all struct (and class) types.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the field in the dataset (`rd:TypeName`) to `System.Nullable (Of System.DateTime)`. Then you can simply test `=Fields!D_DateTime.Value Is Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Marco suggested you can check for `MinValue`. And if you want to pass `NULL` to the nullable parameter, you can use the following code for `reportviewer` parameter.

**Vb.Net**

```
Dim rpFrom As New ReportParameter("FromDate", New String() {Nothing}, False)
```

**C#**

```
ReportParameter rpFrom = new ReportParameter("FromDate", new string[] { null }, false);
```